# Sort dataframe based on custom dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

The dataframe that I have is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Question':['Q2','Q2','Q1','Q1','Q1','Q3','Q3','Q3'],
                    'Answer':['Yes','No','$1 to $49','$100 to $200','$50 to $100','More than 5000','Less than 5000','Don't know']})
```

I would like to sort the dataframe by the column `Question` and `Answer`. I have created a custom dictionary to be used when sorting by `Answer`, so that categorical values can be sorted accordingly.

```
answer_sort_order = {'$1 to $49': 0, '$50 to $100': 1, '$50 to $99': 2, '$100 to $200': 3,'More than 5000': 4, 'Less than 5000': 5, 'Don't Know': 6}
```

How can I use this to get the dataframe like below?

[image]

I can also specify that to only use the `answer_sort_order` dictionary for records in which `Question` is `Q1` and `Q3`

Comment: `df.iloc[np.argsort(df['Answer'].map(answer_sort_order))]`

Comment: @QuangHoang this doesn't sort the dataframe as intended

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `key` parameter of [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
out = df.sort_values('Answer', key=pd.Series(answer_sort_order).reindex)
```

or:

```
out = df.sort_values('Answer', key=lambda x: x.map(answer_sort_order))
```

output:

```
  Question          Answer
2       Q1       $1 to $49
4       Q1     $50 to $100
3       Q1    $100 to $200
5       Q3  More than 5000
6       Q3  Less than 5000
0       Q2             Yes
1       Q2              No
7       Q3      Don't know
```

Comment: Thanks! and then I can do a `out =out.sort_values('Question')` to have it sorted by `Question`

Comment: Yes, you can also pipe the two operations: `out = df.sort_values('Answer', key=lambda x: x.map(answer_sort_order)).sort_values('Question')`

Comment: can you update code so that I define to only use the dictionary `answer_sort_order`  to only sort questions  `Q1` and `Q3` and sort rest of the questions normally? Because as you can see question `Q2` is not getting sorted (it should be the record with `No` appearing in the top and the records with `Yes` appearing after it)